# struggling to combine awk in one pass

Tags: bash, awk, find, grep

After running the command

```
find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1 -exec sh -c 'grep -H ^err "{}" || echo "{}:No error"' \;
```

my files look like this

```
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~40048~jgmdtv113~1~P~R22-200~029053662549~20110607~102151.VER No error
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~ETT03~jgm14652.~3~F~R16-500~000907009757~20110607~085109.VER err 3922
```

Using the tilde (~) symbol as delimiter in the file name, can I extract the fields I want so I get an output like this

```
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~40048~jgmdtv113~1~P~R22-200~029053662549~20110607~102151.VER No error RRR1 COS P
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~ETT03~jgm14652.~3~F~R16-500~000907009757~20110607~085109.VER err 3922 RRR1 COS F
```

I tried the following

```
find . -name "R*VER" -mtime +1 -exec sh -c 'grep -H ^err "{}" || echo "{}:No error"' \;|awk -F~ '{print $0}{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10}'
```

but it does not work; Instead, it produces this output (not all fields shown here...)

```
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~40048~jgmdtv113~1~P~R22-200~029053662549~20110607~102151.VER No error
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~40048~jgmdtv113~1~P~R22-200~029053662549~20110607~102151.VER RRR1 COS P
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~ETT03~jgm14652.~3~F~R16-500~000907009757~20110607~085109.VER err 3922
RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~ETT03~jgm14652.~3~F~R16-500~000907009757~20110607~085109.VER RRR1 COS F
```

I'd like to do this is one pass so I can generate a SQL script with INSERT statements...Can it be done?

Comment: this seems way over-complex. Will you accept an answer that is just `find | xargs awkProg` ? Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help, this is what I got:

`find . -name "R*VER" -exec sh -c 'grep -H ^err "{}" || echo "{}:No error"' \; |
        awk -F: '
                BEGIN { q="\047" }
                {
                        file=$1
                        result=$2
                        sub(/^.*\//,"",file)
                        split(file,a,/~/)
                        print "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8) VALUES (" q file q "," q result q "," q a[1] q "," q a[2] q "," q a[7] q "," q a[8] q "," q a[9] q "," q a[10] q ")"
                }'`

It works great. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

You should use only one action to print everything:

```
awk -F~ {print $0 " " $1 " " $2 " " ...}
```

Comment: awk -F ~ turns into my home folder. awk -F~ doesn't.

Comment: Using `awk -F~ '{print $0 " " $1 " " $2 " "}` works only when for the "No errors" scenario. When errors are found and displayed, your solution does not.

Comment: Followup: this is what is displayed when for the "No errors" scenario
`RRR1~COS~COSMETICS~76545~JGMDTV316~4~P~H21-200~029397314914~20110607~095815.VER:No error RRR1 COS`

Comment: Followup: this is what is displayed when for the "Errors found" scenario
`RRR1 COS OSMETICS~ETT03~jgm14652.~3~F~R16-500~000907009757~20110607~085109.VER:err ->BIST Login Fail 3922 err` 

Notice stripped tilde in file name?